# Best way to model music (notes) for fast searching notes at a particular time

Tags: c++, performance, loops, vector

I'm working on an iOS music app (written in C++) and my model looks more or less like this:

```
--Song
----Track
----Track
------Pattern
------Pattern
--------Note
--------Note
--------Note
```

So basically a `Song` has multiple `Tracks`, a `Track` can have multiple `Patterns` and a `Pattern` has multiple `Notes.` Each one of those things is represented by a class and except for the Song object, they're all stored inside vectors.

Each `Note` has a `"frame"` parameter so that I can calculate when a note should be played. For example, if I have 44100 samples / second and the frame for a particular note is 132300 I know that I need that Note at the start of the third second.

My question is how I should represent those notes for best performance? Right now I'm thinking of storing the notes in a vector datamember of each pattern and than loop all the `Tracks` of the `Song`, than look the `Patterns` and than loop the `Notes` to see which one has a frame datamember that is greater than 132300 and smaller than 176400 (start of 4th second).

As you can tell, that's a lot of loops and a song could be as long as 10 minutes. So I'm wondering if this will be fast enough to calculate all the frames and send them to the buffer on time.

Comment: _"My question is how I should represent those notes for best performance?"_ This depends on what you are going to do with the data.

Comment: Well, each note also has a frequency and a duration. So basically I need those two to calculate the samples (sine calculations mostly)

Comment: Ok, please check the box: `[.] "I'm reinventing MOD files"` or `[.] "I'm reinventing MIDI files"`. Note that [MOD players already exist for smart phones](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/modplayer/id301653160?mt=8)

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm trying to 'reinvent' one of those. Do you suggest using some existing tools maybe? The application you linked to is not open source so it isn't of much use to me.

Comment: @Sled: I think his point is that the AppStore already has programs that do what you are trying to do. And since they use open formats, rather than your home-grown one, people will generally not use yours. So there's likely not much point.

Comment: This is a school project, I doubt they'll be satisfied with that answer. And honestly I don't see why that should matter..

Comment: @Sled: *"I don't see why that should matter"* Reinventing the wheel is a bad programming habit that should be exterminated as soon as possible.

Comment: You are just assuming that I'm making an exact copy of something that already exists while I know that not to be the case. It's hard to be 100% original in anything these days but that's not necessary to make a good product.

Comment: @Sled: Since you haven't mentioned even a single feature that is missing from *.ly, *.mod, *.mid, then by murphy's law you're making exact copy of something that already exists.

Comment: @SigTerm Sled is asking how to store data in memory using standard containers of C++. MIDI and MOD are binary formats for storing the same data on disk, they don't have anything to do with optimizing performance and actually **playing** the music stored in them.

Comment: Are you editing or just playing?

Comment: I'm doing both. New notes can be added or removed at any time, if that's what you mean.

Comment: **As you can tell, that's a lot of loops and a song could be as long as 10 minutes. So I'm wondering if this will be fast enough to calculate all the frames and send them to the buffer on time.**: Run, and if it seems slow, then ask where you need to find speed. So long as your patterns are **sorted** by their starting point you shouldn't have any issues with speed. But first thing's first, prototype, run and test it all, that's the only way you're really going to know anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One thing you should remember is that to improve performance, normally memory consumption would have to increase. It is also relevant (and justified) in this case, because I believe you want to store the same data **twice**, in different ways.

First of all, you should have this basic structure for a song:

```
map<Track, vector<Pattern>> tracks;
```

It maps each `Track` to a vector of `Pattern`s. Map is fine, because you don't care about the order of tracks.

Traversing through `Track`s and `Pattern`s should be fast, as their amounts will not be high (I assume). The main performance concern is to loop through thousands of notes. Here's how I suggest to solve it:

First of all, for each `Pattern` object you should have a `vector<Note>` as your main data storage. You will write all the changes on the `Pattern`'s contents to this `vector<Note>` first.

```
vector<Note> notes;
```

And for performance considerations, you can have a second way of storing notes:

```
map<int, vector<Notes>> measures;
```

This one will map each **measure** (by its number) in a `Pattern` to the vector of `Note`s contained in this measure. Every time data changes in the main `notes` storage, you will apply the same changes to data in `measures`. You could also do it only once every time before the playback, or even *while* playback, in a separate thread.

Of course, you could only store notes in measures, without having to sync two sources of data. But it may be not so convenient to work with when you have to apply mass operations on bunches of notes.

During the playback, before the next measure starts, the following algorithm would happen (roughly):

1. In every track, find all patterns, for which `pattern->startTime <= [current playback second] <= pattern->endTime`.
2. For each pattern, calculate current measure number and get `vector<Notes>` for the corresponding measure from the `measures` map.
3. Now, until the next measure (second?) starts, you only have to loop through current measure's notes.

Comment: I strongly recommend against using a `std::list`. Data locality is usually the most important part of performance, and a `std::list` destroys that. I have never once found a situation in my own code where a `std::list` performs better than a `std::vector` or `std::deque`. Even if you occasionally insert into the middle and are worried about having to shift everything else over if you use a `std::vector`, the time it will take to search the `std::list` will almost always take longer. See slide 43: http://ecn.channel9.msdn.com/events/GoingNative12/GN12Cpp11Style.pdf

Answer (score 3):

Just keep those vectors sorted.

During playback, you can just keep a pointer (index) into each vector for the last note player.  To search for new notes, you check have to check the following note in each vector, no looping through notes required.

Answer (score 1):

Keep your vectors sorted, and try things out - that is more important and any answer you can receive here.

For all of your questions you should *seek* to answer then with **tests** and **prototypes**, then you will know if you even have a problem. And also while trying it out you will see things that you wouldn't normally see with just the theory alone.

Answer (score 0):

> and my model looks more or less like this:

Several critically important concepts are missing from your model:

1. Tempo.
2. [Dynamics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_musical_symbols#Dynamics).
3. [Pedal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_musical_symbols#Pedal_marks)
4. Instrument
5. [Time signature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_signature).
6. (Optional) Tonality.
7. Effect (Reverberation/chorus, pitch wheel).
8. Stereo positioning.
9. Lyrics.
10. Chord maps.
11. Composer information/Title.

> Each Note has a "frame" parameter so that I can calculate when a note should be played.

Several critically important concepts are missing from your model:

1. Articulation.
2. Aftertouch.
3. Note duration.

I'd advise to take a look at [lilypond](http://lilypond.org/). It is typesetting software, but it is also one of the most precise way to represent music in human-readable text format.

> My question is how I should represent those notes for best performance?

Put them all into `std::map<Timestamp, Note>` and find segment you want to playing using lower_bound/upper_bound. Alternatively you could binary search them in flat std::vector as long as data is sorted.

Unless you want to make a "beeper", making music application is much more difficult than you think. I'd strongly recommend to try another project.

Comment: I'm actually already implementing most of the things you mentioned. Not all of them, because some I just don't need (pedal, effect, lyrics and chords)